# How to add an element to array in CodeIgniter controller

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

In my CodeIgniter controller called Leads
I am having a code which retrieve data from model (database):

```
$data['leads'] = $this->model_leads->get_leads_by_person($person_id);
```

Now I can get some fileds like:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [lead_id] => 79 [lead_date] => 2014-07-15 12:34:41 [lead_priv] => 0 [1] => Array ( [lead_id] => 395 [lead_date] => 2014-07-15 12:34:41 [[lead_priv] => 0))
```

Now I want to add to every lead in `$data['leads'`] additional value, in my example **lead_chance**.
So let's say that I have a variable `$lead_chance='100';`

How to add this as an element to an array `$data['leads']`?

Comment: What you print `$data` or `$data['leads']` to get your array??

Comment: @Saty: It was print_r ($data['leady_z_bazy']);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($data['leads'] as $id => $lead) {
    $data['leads'][$id]['lead_chance'] = '100';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
foreach ($data['leads'] as $x) {
   $x['lead_chance']=$lead_chance;
}
```

This would give you one lead_chance per item. If you want only one lead_chance for the whole array, it is much easier:

```
$data['leads']['lead_chance']=$lead_chance;
```